# Weird menu icons after change the theme

Tags: 11.10, themes

I just changed my theme, and now, when I maximize Firefox, my icons look weird
like this

[image]

this is my theme configuration

[image]

any ideas guys? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that's normal.

try reloading the shell when you changed the theme (alt + F2, r)

check http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-enable-altf2-run-command-prompt if your alt-f2 isn't working

Comment: i'm using unity. when i press alt+f2 and r, unity list all the programs that starts with 'r' and executes it. in my case 'radeontool'...on my shortcuts, the option 'show the run command prompt' is disabled and i can't edit.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because your window theme does not have a "windowbuttons" (I forgot the name.. I think it is) theme, so, you can install another window button theme from www.gnome-look.org.

But, I never seen these ugly icons where no windowbutton theme exists, maybe a simple `unity --replace` fix that.